# MySQL, Two billion rows of data, read only, performance optimisations?

Tags: mysql, optimization, database-design, query-optimization, database-performance

I have a set of integer data. The first being the number 0 and the last being 47055833459. There are two billion of these numbers from the first to the last and they will never change or be added to. The only insert into the mysql table will be loading this data into it. From then on, it will only be read from.

I predict the size of the database table to be roughly 20Gb. I plan on having two columns:

```
id, data
```

Id will be a primary key, auto incremented unsigned INT and data will be an unsigned BIGINT

What will be the best way of optimising this data for read only with those two columns? I have looked at the other questions which are similar but they all take into account write speeds and ever increasing tables. The host I am using does not support MySQL partitioning so unfortunately this is not an option at the moment. If it turns out that partitioning is the only way, then I will reconsider a new host.

The table will only ever be accessed by the id column so there does not need to be an index on the data column.

So to summarise, what is the best way of handling a table with 2 billion rows with two columns, without partitioning, optimised for reads, in MySQL?

Comment: What kind of queries are you running on the data?

Comment: The only kind of query that will ever be run on the table is: "SELECT id, data FROM table WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1", the database user will be limited to only SELECTs as well

Comment: I don't think you need the `limit 1`.  Declaring the `id` as a primary key is sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: Is id intended to express some kind of meaningful order on this set?  Or is it just a meaningless identifier that gets its order from the order in which the numbers were entered.

Comment: What advantage is gained by storing the id as a foreign key elsewhere instead of just storing a copy of the BIGINT itself?

Comment: @walter, the data has its position in the set of numbers. It just so happens that the way the data will be inserted into the database will match up with the auto increments. so every number from one to a billion will have an associated data set

Comment: So the ID field carries information about not only identity, but also order.  Correct?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using InnnDB, you should simply:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    ID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    DATA BIGINT UNSIGNED
);
```

This will effectively create one big B-Tree and nothing else, and retrieving a row by ID can be done in a single index seek<sup>1</sup>. Take a look at ["Understanding InnoDB clustered indexes"](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/) for more info.

---

<sup>1</sup> Without table heap access, in fact there is no heap at all.

Answer (score 0):

Define your table like so.

```
CREATE TABLE `lkup` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `data`)
)
```

The compound primary key will consume disk space, but will make lookups very fast; your queries can be satisfied just by reading the index (which is known as a *covering index*).

And, do `OPTIMIZE TABLE lkup` when you're finished loading your static data into it. That may take a while, but it will pay off big at runtime.

Comment: edit to eliminate a redundant index, and make the primary key the covering index.

Comment: Assuming InnoDB, `PRIMARY KEY (id)` also covers the query, which is a  consequence of how clustering works. Furthermore, `PRIMARY KEY (id, data)` compromises data integrity (allows duplicated IDs).

Comment: I doubt the `AUTO_INCREMENT` is desired. Sounds like he's picking his 2 billion IDs (from within the set [0, 47055833459]) very carefully.

Comment: The reason I used auto_increment is because I will be loading the data in chunks and instead of manually inserting the ID, i figured I would leave that to MySQL. After the two billion rows are inserted, I could remove the AUTO_INCREMENT property if it would help performance. Would auto increment add a big hit to performance for reads?